# How to pass login parameters for a graphql request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, graphql

I have recorded a login use case using JMeter. My application uses Graphql requests for authentication.
From my recordings, I can see the POST query. However, I am not seeing the provided username and password anywhere in JMeter.

In case of providing login with new user details, where and how should I provide the user credentials?

> POST data:
> {"operationName":"getDetails","variables":{},"query":"query getDetails {\n  user {\n    email\n    fullName\n    id\n    name\n  }\n}\n"}

Answer (score 0):

As per [Authentication and Express Middleware](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/authentication-and-express-middleware/) GraphQL user manual chapter:

> In a REST API, authentication **is often handled with a header**, that contains an auth token which proves what user is making this request. Express middleware processes these headers and puts authentication data on the Express request object. Some middleware modules that handle authentication like this are Passport, express-jwt, and express-session. Each of these modules works with express-graphql.

So check the recorded test plan for [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager), most probably it contain some token which identifies the current user.

If the authentication is external, provided by ingress or reverse proxy, the details will be in the [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

Comment: I couldn't find the user details in HTTP Header / HTTP Authorization Managers. However, as you said, I could see the authorization token is generated in my next request.

I understand the generated token is for the given user. I'm still thinking about how to pass a new user to the same script.